# Smoke particle system

Tags: c#, performance, animation, xna, monogame

Please note that I'm working on a game on Windows Phone 8 using Monogame. The game is fine (60 FPS) all the time, except when the particle system is activated. This is just a smoke particle system that begins to emit when the player jumps and stop to emit as the player is at "0" y velocity after the jump. When this particle system is activated it goes down to 20-30 FPS, which is very frustrating.

I watched my game with a profiler and it says that the bottleneck is here at the particle system, in particular with `Update`/`Draw` functions.

What can I do to improve it?

**The particle**

```
public class Particle : IDisposable
{
    public Texture2D texture_ { get; set; } 
    public Vector2 position_ { get; set; }  
    public Vector2 velocity_ { get; set; }

    public float angle_ { get; set; }
    public float angular_velocity_ { get; set; }

    public Color color_ { get; set; }            
    public float scale_ { get; set; }
    // The 'time to live' of the particle
    public int TTL { get; set; }

    private Rectangle source_rectangle_;
    private Vector2 origin_;

    public Particle(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Vector2 velocity,
        float angle, float angularVelocity, Color color, float size, int ttl)
    {
        texture_ = texture;
        position_ = position;
        velocity_ = velocity;
        angle_ = angle;
        angular_velocity_ = angularVelocity;
        color_ = color;
        scale_ = size;
        TTL = ttl;

        source_rectangle_ = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture_.Width, texture_.Height);
        origin_ = new Vector2(texture_.Width / 2, texture_.Height / 2);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        --TTL;
        position_ += velocity_ * elapsed;
        angle_ += angular_velocity_ * elapsed;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            texture_,
            position_,
            source_rectangle_,
            color_,
            angle_,
            origin_,
            scale_,
            SpriteEffects.None,
            0f);
    }
}
```

**The particle emitter**

```
public class ParticleEngine : IDisposable
{
    private static Random random_;
    private Vector2 emitter_location_ = Vector2.Zero;
    private LinkedList<Particle> particles_;
    private LinkedList<Particle> fading_particles_;
    private List<Texture2D> active_textures_;

    private int spread_factor_ = 160;
    private int density_ = 5;

    private bool enabled_ = true;

    private Color[] list_of_colors_ = new Color[] { 
        new Color(111, 86, 41) * 0.8f,
        new Color(65, 44, 32) * 0.8f,
        Color.LawnGreen * 0.8f,
        Color.Yellow * 0.8f
        };

    public ParticleEngine(List<Texture2D> textures, Vector2 location)
    {
        random_ = GameManager.random_;
        emitter_location_ = location;
        this.active_textures_ = textures;
        this.particles_ = new LinkedList<Particle>();
        this.fading_particles_ = new LinkedList<Particle>();

        active_textures_ = Loader.scoregge_;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        for (LinkedListNode<Particle> p = particles_.Last; p != particles_.First; p = p.Previous)
            p.Value.Dispose();

        for (LinkedListNode<Particle> p = fading_particles_.Last; p != fading_particles_.First; p = p.Previous)
            p.Value.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return enabled_; }
    }

    public Vector2 EmitterLocation
    {
        get { return emitter_location_; }
        set
        {
            enabled_ = true;
            emitter_location_ = value;
        }
    }

    private Particle GenerateNewParticle()
    {
        Texture2D texture = active_textures_[random_.Next(active_textures_.Count)];
        Vector2 position = emitter_location_;
        Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(
                 (float)(random_.NextDouble() * spread_factor_),
                 (float)(random_.NextDouble() * spread_factor_));
        float angle = 0;
        float angularVelocity = (float)(random_.NextDouble() * 5);
        Color color = list_of_colors_[random_.Next(list_of_colors_.Count())];
        float size = (float)random_.NextDouble();
        int ttl = 15 + random_.Next(30);

        return new Particle(texture, position, velocity, angle, angularVelocity, color, size, ttl);
    }

    public void StopEmitting()
    {
        LinkedListNode<Particle> p = particles_.Last;
        while (p != null)
        {
            fading_particles_.AddLast(p.Value);
            particles_.RemoveLast();

            p = p.Previous;
        }

        enabled_ = false;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (enabled_)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < density_; i++)
            {
                particles_.AddLast(GenerateNewParticle());
            }
        }

        LinkedListNode<Particle> p = particles_.Last;
        while (p != null)
        {
            LinkedListNode<Particle> p_prev = p.Previous;            
            Particle particle = p.Value;

            particle.Update(gameTime);

            if (particle.TTL <= 0)
            {
                fading_particles_.AddLast(particle);
                particles_.Remove(p);
            }

            p = p_prev;
        }

        p = fading_particles_.Last;
        while (p != null)
        {
            LinkedListNode<Particle> p_prev = p.Previous;
            Particle particle = p.Value;

            particle.Update(gameTime);
            particle.color_ *= 0.98f;

            if (particle.color_.A <= 0.0f)
            {
                fading_particles_.Remove(p);
            }

            p = p_prev;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        LinkedListNode<Particle> p = particles_.Last;
        while (p != null)
        {
            p.Value.Draw(spriteBatch);
            p = p.Previous;
        }

        p = fading_particles_.Last;
        while (p != null)
        {
            p.Value.Draw(spriteBatch);
            p = p.Previous;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the root of the problem is using Linked Lists. Have a read of this discussion about why in C#, the general case is `List<T>` will outperform `LinkedList<T>` most of the time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983059/why-is-a-linkedlist-generally-slower-than-a-list

In particular, the `Update` method is calling `AddLast` a lot. This is not very efficient when using linked lists. Calling `Remove` is probably also quite slow.

SebastianStehle is right that there are lots of little micro-optimizations you can do to improve the performance, but I think (without profiling the code myself) you can get the biggest bang for buck by changing the `LinkedList`'s to `List`'s, or even better, fixed sized arrays.

The next thing probably is to limit the number of memory allocations (calling new) for each particle. There are a few ways to do this. One simple idea is to use flags on the particles instead of adding and removing them from the lists. Perhaps `IsActive` and `IsFading` in your case.

Oh, one last thing.. I just noticed this line:

```
Texture2D texture = active_textures_[random_.Next(active_textures_.Count)];
```

Be very careful that you're not switching textures a lot. In modern graphics hardware, switching textures is one of the biggest bottlenecks. If you need to support different shaped particles consider storing them in a texture atlas.

Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: [Difference between List and fixed sized arrays is negligible - when not using foreach.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists)

Comment: I agree. In most cases using lists are fine, but removing memory allocations from the equation can help. For the record, my particle system uses lists. I haven't had a reason to optimize it yet

Comment: @craftworkgames Are talking about a smartphone game? Because I felt the need of optimize just when I put my game on the device.

Comment: @misiMe It's pretty typical to need to optimize when you put the game on a smartphone device since they don't have the processing power of desktop PC's. Although, I wasn't talking about smartphones in particular, just optimizations in general. As a general rule you shouldn't optimize until after you've profiled / measured. Although, with experience you'll know the type of code that can get you into trouble and avoid creating slow code in the first place. I like to focus on creating clean, simple, maintainable code and optimizing when I need too.

Answer (score 9):

I don't have a solution, but here are some tips:

1. Measuring the difference between structs and classes for particles can make a difference.
2. Do not use properties for particles; use simple fields.
3. Calculate values once (e.g. pass `totalseconds` to your particles, not `gametime`).
4. Use object pooling for your particles; don't create them on the fly.
5. Decide how many particles you want to support and use simple structures like arrays.
6. Draw the particles manually without `spritebatch`.
7. Calculate everything you need at the beginning; don't create new objects.

Some of the tips are micro-optimizations and are totally useless in other scenarios, but they are very helpful in particle systems.